# Sequelize includes reference table row in result when using include

Tags: sequelize.js

I have `Track` and `Artist` models defined, with association as follows:

```
db.Track.belongsToMany(db.Artist, {through: 'TracksArtists'});
db.Artist.belongsToMany(db.Track, {through: 'TracksArtists'});
```

I want to search for Tracks and include Artist.name in the results:

```
db.Track
    findAll({ 
        attributes: ['title','year'], 
        where: { title: { like: '%' + string + '%' } },
        include: [{model: db.Artist, attributes: ['name']}]
    })
    .complete(function(err, tracks){ /*...*/});
```

However, Sequelize also includes a row from TracksArtists reference table in the results:

```
[{"title":"Nightcall","year":2010,"Artists":[{"name":"Kavinsky","TracksArtists":{"createdAt":"2015-01-13T18:41:31.850Z","updatedAt":"2015-01-13T18:41:31.850Z","ArtistId":1,"TrackId":1}}]}]
```

which is unnecessary. How can I make it not to return info from TracksArtists, instead of having to remove it on my own?

Comment: Try `include: [{model: db.Artist, attributes: ['name'], through: {attributes: []}}]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can turn off join table attributes by passing an empty attributes array to through like:

`include: [{model: db.Artist, attributes: ['name'], through: {attributes: []}}]`

Comment: In my scenario, one of the attributes in the `through` table is a foreign key for another model. I tried including the name in the `attributes: []` but get the index, not the model. Any thoughts on how to include a model in the `through` table?

Answer (score 1):

I have `Faq` and `Artist` models defined, with association as follows:

```
Faq.belongsToMany(Version, { through: FaqVersion, foreignKey: 'faqId' });
Version.belongsToMany(Faq, { through: FaqVersion, foreignKey: 'verId' });
```

I encountered the same problem with the author, but i add:

```
models.Version.findAll({
  raw: true,
  attributes: ['id', 'version'],
  include: [{
    model: models.Faq,
    attributes: [],
    through: { attributes: [] },
    where: {
    id: faq.id
    }
 }]
})
```

However, Sequelize also includes a row from FaqVersion reference table in the results:

```
Faqs.FaqVersion.createdAt:"2017-01-10T05:22:06.000Z",
Faqs.FaqVersion.faqId:2,
Faqs.FaqVersion.id:3,
Faqs.FaqVersion.updatedAt:"2017-01-10T05:22:06.000Z",
Faqs.FaqVersion.verId:2,
id:2,
version:"5.2.6"
```

I think `through` does not work

Answer (score 0):

just use syntax like this :

```
include: [
            {
                model: ModelName,
                through: {attributes: []}
            }
    ]
```